# Using a lambda function in np.fromfunction with an if statement depending on `i` and `j`

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I do not know how to insert the `if` statement `if (i + j) % 2 == 0` into a lambda function. It is not as straightforward as a single variable.

Here is my attempt

```
# dummy values
two_at = 4.5 
n = 5
m = 6
# fromfunction with lambda function
matrix = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: 1 / (two_at) ** ((i+j)/2) if (i+j) % 2 == 0 else 0.0, (n+1, m+1))
```

The error I get is

`matrix = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: 1 / (two_at) ** ((i+j)/2) if (i+j) % 2 == 0 else 0.0, (n + 1, m + 1))` 
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I would be more than satisfied with any answer that is faster than a double for loop such as

```
   matrix = np.zeros((n,m))
   for i in range(n + 1):
       for j in range(m + 1):
           m = i + j
           if m % 2 == 0:
               matrix[i,j] = 1 / (two_at) ** (m/2)
```

Comment: Just write a regular `def` function - lambdas are limited to a single expression, which makes it hard to read anything non-trivial.

Comment: are you sure you get that error for this code or is there other code besides this one?

Comment: @NikosM. Too ugly to post here, I updated question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I will look into this, thanks for the advice. Part of my problem is how do I pass `two_at` to the function? I get how to use `fromfunction` if passing only indices. I will read the docs, it must be in there. numpy docs have never let me down before. I think `programcreek` has some examples. Looks like it isn't an issue so long as I make the function inside the function that defines two_at.

Comment: `fromfunction` generates all indices and passes then as arrays to your function.  Your function expects scalar `i,j`, not 2d arrays.  `fromfunction` is the **wrong** function for this.

Comment: @hpaulj it works, but is really slow. A double for loop is many times faster :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [41]: two_at = 2                                                                     
In [42]: def func(i, j): 
    ...:         m = i + j 
    ...:         return np.where(m % 2 == 0, 1 / (two_at) ** (m / 2), 0) 
    ...:  
    ...: matrix = np.fromfunction(func, (4 + 1, 4 + 1))                                 
In [43]: matrix                                                                         
Out[43]: 
array([[1.    , 0.    , 0.5   , 0.    , 0.25  ],
       [0.    , 0.5   , 0.    , 0.25  , 0.    ],
       [0.5   , 0.    , 0.25  , 0.    , 0.125 ],
       [0.    , 0.25  , 0.    , 0.125 , 0.    ],
       [0.25  , 0.    , 0.125 , 0.    , 0.0625]])
```

With this `func`, `fromfunction` doesn't buy us much; just pass broadcastable 1d arrays instead:

```
In [44]: func(np.arange(5)[:,None], np.arange(5))                                       
Out[44]: 
array([[1.    , 0.    , 0.5   , 0.    , 0.25  ],
       [0.    , 0.5   , 0.    , 0.25  , 0.    ],
       [0.5   , 0.    , 0.25  , 0.    , 0.125 ],
       [0.    , 0.25  , 0.    , 0.125 , 0.    ],
       [0.25  , 0.    , 0.125 , 0.    , 0.0625]])
```

In my other answer I used multiplication to apply the `cond` to the results.

As for the comparison with loops.  Timings with a small example often favor list and iterative solutions.  `numpy` fares much better when sizes are in the 1000s.

Some timings:

```
In [55]: timeit matrix = np.fromfunction(func, (4 + 1, 4 + 1))                          
47.2 µs ± 94.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [56]: timeit func(np.arange(5)[:,None], np.arange(5))                                
33.7 µs ± 112 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [61]: %%timeit 
    ...: res = np.zeros((5,5)) 
    ...: for i in range(5): 
    ...:     for j in range(5): 
    ...:         m=i+j 
    ...:         if m%2==0: 
    ...:             res[i,j] = 1/(two_at)** (m/2) 
    ...:              
    ...:                                                                                

9.77 µs ± 26.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

But increase the size:

```
In [62]: %%timeit 
    ...: res = np.zeros((500,500)) 
    ...: for i in range(500): 
    ...:     for j in range(500): 
    ...:         m=i+j 
    ...:         if m%2==0: 
    ...:             res[i,j] = 1/(two_at)** (m/2) 
    ...:              
    ...:                                                                                             
71.9 ms ± 206 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [63]: timeit func(np.arange(500)[:,None], np.arange(500))                                         
33.3 ms ± 65.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj. Unfortunately these loops are the 7th and 8th loops in a nested set, but will never be passed anything very large. I have been trying to broadcast, but it is to no avail on these little loops. I need to go out one level and broadcast over 4 loops I think, or use JIT. These loops get called alot :S

Answer (score 1):

One solution as mentioned by jonrsharpe is to define a function.

```
def func(i, j):
        m = i + j
        return np.where(m % 2 == 0, 1 / (two_at) ** (m / 2), 0)

matrix = np.fromfunction(func, (n + 1, n + 1))
```

Comment: this is incredibly slow. A double for loop is many times faster.